# Adsense Pageviews Tank Since Move to HTTPS (other metrics stable)

Tags: google-adsense

I moved my website from http to https last week, and since then pageviews in Google Adsense (not Analytics) have tanked -- from over 10K normally to the low hundreds. All other metrics have remained stable, including impressions, clicks, revenue and Analytics traffic (which remains above 10K). Does anyone have an idea of whether adding the SSL would have such an impact on Adsense revenue? Is this possibly an Adsense bug, and the timing just a coincidence?

Edited to add, I did add the following code to my .htaccess file, in case that helps:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Could that be conflicting with this preexisting code?

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[sitename].com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.[sitename].com/$1 [R=301,L]

Thanks,
J

Comment: Have you tried updating the second rule you posted, so that it always goes to the https version?

Comment: Thanks for replying; I just made that change and will update if it solves the issue.

Comment: It doesn't look like that was the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have figured out the problem. I had inserted this Google auto ads code into my header around the same time I switched to the HTTPS:

(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1234567891234567",
    enable_page_level_ads: true,
    overlays: {bottom: true}
  });

It finally occurred to me today that the above code might have been the problem. I removed it, and since then my pageviews are back toward normal. Something to keep in mind if you're ever planning to use auto ads.